# Invalid configuration object output.path is not an absolute path

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I try compile ".ts" to ".js" with webpack but getting this error, how can I fix this?

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "./dist" is not an absolute path!"
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`output.path`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-path) requires an absolute path, but you're giving it a relative path `./dist`. You need to convert it to an absolute path, for instance by using [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    // Your other output options
  },
  // Rest of your config
};
```

Comment: Thanks it's help me!

Comment: I got the same issue after installing SASS ***

npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev

 the given solution got worked. what is the reason? since when I started working, it dosen't given any issues on the path.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742252/invalid-configuration-object-configuration-output-path-after-installing-sass