# Invalid configuration object in webpack

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am following [Lynda.com - React.js essential training](https://www.lynda.com/React-js-tutorials/React-js-Essential-Training/496905-2.html) by Eve Porcello. In the video "Building with Webpack", I followed the steps author described exactly, but the "webpack" command failed giving the following error,

**Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "dist/assets" is not an absolute path!**

Following are my webpack.config.js and package.json files.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: "dist/assets",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "assets"
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: "./dist",
    port: 3000
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["latest", "stage-0", "react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-essential",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A project focusing on React and related tools",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "httpster -d ./dist -p 3000"
  },
  "author": "Indu Pillai",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I repeated the steps again and again, but it's not working. I'm pretty new to this webpack thing, so I'm not able to find out what the problem really is, and what kind of absolute path it requires. I also tried an absolute path suggested by some answer to another (similar) question, but that didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid configuration object output.path is not an absolute path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028487/invalid-configuration-object-output-path-is-not-an-absolute-path)

Comment: The duplicate you provided didn't work for me.

Answer (score 20):

This will compile with latest webpack - as of Apr 10, 2017:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist/assets",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: __dirname + "/dist",
        port: 3000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: ["babel-loader"],
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the [ ] around the "babel-loader".

Comment: "replace ~loaders~ by ~rules~", as Leo Leao says below, is the actual answer. This code block doesn't explain that at all.

Answer (score 5):

I am doing the same course as you and I had to do the following to get Webpack to output the bundle.js file correctly:

1. Uninstall the latest webpack (2, if you just used `npm install webpack`)
2. Then in terminal run `npm install -g webpack@1.13.3` (she recommends using `sudo npm install -g` so it's up to you on that one to use `sudo` or not)
3. The next issue few issues webpack was throwing may only apply to me but I had to `require('path')` because I got non-resolving path errors, and also had to `npm install babel-loader` because it wasn't being loaded through the `package.json` file for whatever reason, that also needed a `path.resolve` addition for the `node_modules` folder
4. My `webpack.config` file looks like the following now:

   ```
   const webpack = require('webpack');
   const path = require('path');

   module.exports = {
       entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index'),
       output: {
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/assets'),
           filename: 'bundle.js',
           publicPath: 'assets'
       },
       devServer: {
           inline: true,
           contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
           port: 3000
       },
       module: {
           loaders: [{
               test: /\.js$/,
               exclude: /(node_modules)/,
               loader: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/babel-loader'),
               query: {
                   presets: ['latest', 'stage-0', 'react']
               }
           }]
       }
   }
   ```
5. Finally, running `webpack --display-error-details` showed me what the errors were, but the config file I pasted here worked for me in the end.

It should be noted that this will (hopefully) allow you to finish the course itself, but it won't help you learn what was updated or needs to be migrated in order to stay current and use Webpack 2. There are other answers here that deal with migrating that should be looked into as well.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 4):

replace ~loaders~ by ~rules~

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
```

Apparently the word loaders here was replaced by rules, so the correct should be:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
```

Comment: THANK YOU! There are old examples all over the Internet which use "loaders" instead of "rules", and this is the fix.

Comment: For anyone doing the full stack javascript tutorial with Sumar Buma who ran into this problem this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

This tutoriel was done with the version 1 of Webpack but you uses a most recent version 2.

You can follow this migration guide to make your code run: https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/

Here is your upgraded configuration

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var folder = __dirname;

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: folder + "dist/assets",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/assets"
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: folder + "dist",
    port: 3000
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["latest", "stage-0", "react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What was the error? I could have make a mistake with my code.

Comment: Migration Guide linked to is a 404.

Comment: I've updated the link to the new migration guide: https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is little difficult than create-react-app. 
the simplest and easiest way to create react projects by using following commands by https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app hello-world
cd hello-world
npm start
```

You can follow all react code from the course but expect webpack because create-react-app compile jsx code and do every thing of webpack etc.

Comment: Thank You, I know that method, but I want to follow the tutorial in the exact steps they did.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, in the exercise files, the instructor uses this syntax for the babel loader:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: ["babel-loader"],
        query: {
            presets: ["latest", "stage-0", "react"]
        }
    },
]
```

which fails on webpack 2.5.0 with an error:

```
Error: options/query cannot be used with loaders (use options for each array item)
```

This is solved by removing the brackets around "babel-loader":

```
loader: "babel-loader", //no brackets - not an array
```

or by specifying the loader and its corresponding options through the "use" syntax:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['latest', 'stage-0', 'react']
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Hopefully they get that fixed over there at Lynda! These new technologies evolve so rapidly! For more info on the babel-loader: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Answer (score 0):

when you migrate into new version of webpack, this error will occur. For solving this your have to provide absolute path to your directory like this

```
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the output.path as absolute path

You can add the following line in the front of webpack.config.js

```
 var path = require('path')
```

and change the output to the following

```
 output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/assets"),
   filename: "bundle.js",
   publicPath: "assets"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work with latest version of webpack v3 you need to make few chages to webpack.config.js file. Your code should look like this after updating

```
            var webpack = require("webpack");
            var path = require('path')

            module.exports = {
                entry: path.resolve(__dirname + "/src/index.js"),
                output: {
                    path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/dist/assets"),
                    filename: "bundle.js",
                    publicPath: "assets"
                },
                devServer: {
                    inline: true,
                    contentBase: __dirname + '/dist',
                    port: 3000
                },
                module: {
                    loaders: [
                        {
                            test: /\.js$/,
                            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                            options: {
                                presets: ["latest", "stage-0", "react"]
                            }
                        }
                }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

and your package.json file should look like this

```
    {
      "name": "activity-counter-application",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "A project focusing on building Activity Counter using React and related tools",
      "main": "./index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server"
      },
      "author": "RJ",
      "license": "MIT",
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "webpack": "^3.5.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^15.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added the `const path = require('path');` to the top of your **webpack.config.js** file and path should be like `path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets'),`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and a little more. So I created a shell script to make the installation process simpler and faster.

---

for **Linux Users**

try this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script [auto_conf_wb](https://github.com/k-five/auto_conf_wb) and it

- downloads
- installs
- configure `webpack`
- configure `babel`
- configure `sever`

for you.

Note that is only for using `ES6+`, `webpack`, `babel` together.