# configuration.output.path: The provided value "./" is not an absolute path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I have got an error : 
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "./" is not an absolute path!

while installing reactjs My package.json file down below

```
{
  "name": "reactset",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "test"
  ],
  "author": "test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
using upgraded node version 4.0 and npm 5.0 
Error : 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactset@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the reactset@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Please help for solving solution : 
Url which help for installing :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

Comment: Have you read the error? It tells you exactly what is wrong with it.... replace configuration.output.path value with a full path to output folder, or use the `path.join(__dirname, 'dist')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid configuration object output.path is not an absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028487/invalid-configuration-object-output-path-is-not-an-absolute-path)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please Change

```
 output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   }
```

To

```
 output: {
      path: __dirname+'/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   }
```

Or in other words change `path: __dirname + '/'`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ES modules, use this:

```
output: {
  path: process.cwd(),
  filename: 'index.js',
}
```

or

```
output: {
  path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
  filename: 'index.js',
}
```